# Active Record in CodeIgniter Incrementing More Than It Should

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I posted this in the CodeIgniter forums the other day and haven't recieved a response, so I'm trying here. It appears that for some reason, my auto increment value in my table is being incremented by 2 instead of 1 after I do a delete statement followed by an insert statement.

Here the is the create syntax for my table.

```
CREATE TABLE `brokerage_zip_range` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
     `zip_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
     `brokerage_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I have code that looks like this in a model:

```
public function assign_zip_range($brokerage_id, $zip_code) {
     $this->db->where('brokerage_id',$brokerage_id);
     $this->db->delete('brokerage_zip_range');

     $this->db->set('brokerage_id', $brokerage_id);
     $this->db->set('zip_code', $zip_code);
     $this->db->insert('brokerage_zip_range'); 
}
```

(Please note that for reasons I won’t get into here, I can’t just make this an update statement).

The problem I am having is that while this code executes fine, the inserted record is incremented by more than one. So, prior to the execution of this code, the record might look like:

```
id    zip_code brokerage_id
7     95202     2
```

After I run the code (say, with zip code 92222), it now looks like:

```
id    zip_code brokerage_id
9     92222     2
```

The next auto increment value should be 8, not 9.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a CI thing? I will point out that I have tried running this code by itself in CI, meaning there are no other operations happening at all before or after it. If it makes a difference (and I doubt it does) I am using CI 2.0/MySQL 5.01/PHP 5.3.

**UPDATE! I FOUND THE ANSWER**
So in the end, it turns out that a custom MY_Router class I was using (so I could have more than one level of controllers without having to resort to manual routing) was apparently calling everything twice. I noticed this when I went and worked on a completely different section of the code, and saw that it was inserting two records of the same data instead of one. I removed that class and now everything is fine again.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I bet that you are calling `assign_zip_range` twice...

Comment: Have you tried to pass an array to the insert function? Something like... `$data = array(
               'title' => 'My title' ,
               'name' => 'My Name' ,
               'date' => 'My date'
            );

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);` It shouldn't make a difference but its worth a shot

Comment: show the controller call that calls this model method

Comment: auto_increment in mysql has an option to increment by any number... Check that just to make sure...

Comment: @linepogl - I am not calling it twice. I created an empty controller and called just that one function, so I'm sure it's not that.

@Peter - Where can I find this?

Comment: you can check that using SHOW CREATE {tablename}

Comment: @silent I did do that, it's the SQL statement in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

I really really doubt that it is CI doing this. Try outputting the SQL generated by the CI AR by:

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

so that you can see what it SQL it runs on your database.

Answer (score 1):

**For others with Flash content in their view:**

I found out that Flash player was forcing my page to make a second request. In my case it was loading a video. The solution to my problem was to place the flash embed into a separate html file and load that html file into an iframe in the offending view.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answer your question. But, try [profiling](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html) your app by adding:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

on your `__construct()`

and see if it's indeed only one INSERT call.

Comment: can I see your profiler's log? if it contain password or something else, replace it first. Same goes to IP/Domain. But, don't change the query.